# Time Zone issue in xpages time control

Tags: xpages, ssjs

I hope you guys are doing good. I am using date and time control on front end for selection of Time from date and time control and only time is visible at front end. My users are using different timezone.

(UTC +09) Osaka, Singapore, Tokyo
(UTC +05)  Tashkant

Now data stored in time field is different in binding field. How can I override field data using SSJS to keep all users in single timezone. 
e.g. i want to using UTC +05 for all users having different zones.

Kindly let me know if you require any clarification about my question.

Thanks,
Qaiser

Comment: Try to use convertToZone when saving the document. http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/lotusscript/lotusscript.nsf/1efb1287fc7c27388525642e0074f2b6/12d876b01bd057858525642e00754d5f?OpenDocument

Comment: 1) date is stored with timezone of server saving the document. Do you have multiple servers in different zones? 2) Date is rendered with timezone of browser according to local OS/browser setting, no matter what timezone was saved. Give more info, please.

Comment: @FrantisekKossuth Thanks for quick response. We are having multiple servers but all are in same timezone but some computer on client side in same locations are having separate time zone as OS level, browser is also inheriting same timezone. That is creating problem. Should I change time zone at server level?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this info](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/XPagesTimeZones.htm) you can automaticaly convert date/time field to specific time zone natively.

Try this example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view
    xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoDocument
            var="document1"
            formName="FRM">
        </xp:dominoDocument>
    </xp:this.data>
    <xp:label
        value="UTC Tashkent:"
        id="label1"
        for="computedField1">
    </xp:label>
    <xp:inputText
        id="inputText1"
        value="#{document1.utc5}"
        defaultValue="#{javascript:@Now()}">
        <xp:this.converter>
            <xp:convertDateTime
                timeZone="Asia/Tashkent"
                type="time"></xp:convertDateTime>
        </xp:this.converter>
        <xp:dateTimeHelper></xp:dateTimeHelper>
        <xp:eventHandler
            event="onclick"
            submit="true"
            refreshMode="complete">
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:inputText>

    &#160;Your UTC: &#160;<xp:text
        escape="true"
        id="computedField1"
        value="#{document1.utc5}">
        <xp:this.converter>
            <xp:convertDateTime
                type="time"></xp:convertDateTime>
        </xp:this.converter>
    </xp:text>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:button
        value="Save"
        id="button1">
        <xp:eventHandler
            event="onclick"
            submit="true"
            refreshMode="complete">
            <xp:this.action>
                <xp:saveDocument
                    var="document1"></xp:saveDocument>
            </xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
</xp:view>
```

The page forces edit box to be **shown** in Tashkent time zone, regardless of browser's settings. Be aware, that stored value may be different, if server's time zone is different from the forced one.

Comment: thanks for prompt response. Can you please share sample code in SSJS because I have tried but failed to get desired results.